# How to I enable or disable notifications for comments on Facebook ads?

Tags: facebook-notifications, facebook-ads

There is no setting for 'Comments on Facebook ads' anywhere to be seen in Facebook business manager or under my personal notification settings?

We used to receive notifications of every comment on every ad we run (these ads are 'unpublished' posts). But they suddenly stopped. My boss is going nuts! How can I turn them back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to finally figure this one out.

Like I said we *used* to get these and they suddenly stopped. No notification setting seemed to apply.

I went to one of the existing email comments and clicked 'Unsubscribe' at the bottom.

[image]

On this unsubscribe page I got a clue

[image]

Then on your notification settings click 'Edit' next to 'Email' and search for `Comments on your links` and click `Turn On` next to it

You must also enable `Comments on your videos` and possibly other options.

[image]

There may be other settings to turn on related to 'Links'. I'm not quite sure how a 'link' is an ad comment but it seems to be the one to enable.